# Magento Tracking script for confirmation page

Tags: magento, tracking

I need to add a tracking script to the confirmation page. The values required to be input are the Order Id and the total amount of the order less vat.

I think I've got the order id sorted: getOrderId(); ?>

But I can't find out how to get the total amount less vat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it for Google Adwords tracking. Basically by using the subtotal on the last order.

```
<?php
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$adwords_saleamt = $order_details->subtotal; 
?>

/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = ****your_id****;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "*****your_label******";
var google_conversion_value = <?php echo $adwords_saleamt; ?>;
/* ]]> */
```

Comment: OK, well come back if you need more explanation.  I normally include it in a separate template file and add it before_body_end in the checkout_onepage_success section of catalog.xml

Comment: Thanks. I havn't approved the answer yet because, I havn't tried it. but thank you in advance :)